# macOS Application Bundle Frameworks Directory Codesign

Tags: macos, frameworks, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I am packing my macOS application into an application bundle. I need to codesign it and pass notarisation. It is possible to put the frameworks in the "Resources" directory?

I have two frameworks. Normally, I used to put such frameworks into the "Frameworks" directory of the bundle. However, for (stupid) designing reason I need to have some more libraries in the same directory of my frameworks. Since such libraries will prevent code signing if placed in the directory "Frameworks", I want to move frameworks + extra libraries into the "Resources" directory.

Reading Apple documentation it seems that frameworks should - of course - belong to the "Frameworks" directory, however I could not find any reference to what should NOT be included into the "Resources" directory. Is this bad practice? Would my .app structure not pass gatekeeper?

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already tried putting a frameworks in `Resources` by now.  As you said, even if it works today, this is not a good idea.

You might be able to work around whatever issue caused you to want to do this by using the `install_name_tool` to [change one of the paths built into your frameworks](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html).  Adding symbolic links are another handy device for issues like this.  This kind of stuff can be done automatically in a *Run Script Build Phase* or a Build Phase *Post Action*.